# Пытаюсь вычислить по формуле ln2 с заданным n

Tags: c++, математика, ряды, численные-методы

Чем отличается мой код от кода, найденного мною [тут](https://gist.github.com/soutoner/4155946). И как сделать так, что бы вычислить в последовательности, к примеру , от n= 6, до n =74.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

    int main(){   
    int n;
    double res1 =0;
    double res =1;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        res1 += (pow(-1,i+1))/i;     
    }
  cout << res1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неэффективное решение использовать `pow`, плюс этот ряд сходится, но очень медленно (для получения точности в n знаков грубо надо 10^n членов), лучше использовать другие ряды. Типа 2\*(1/(1\*3) + 1/(3\*3^3) + 1/(5\*3^5 + ...)

Comment: Плюсы тут каким боком?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, по ссылке вообще кромешный ужас...

У вас чуть меньший, но... Вы считаете по формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(которая сходится для x из (-1,1], но для `x == 1` делает это *очень* медленно, для точности n знаков надо 10<sup>n</sup> слагаемых...)

Даже так вид формулы наводит на совершенно иной код (ладно, пусть, как у вас, для количества членов...):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) res += ((i%2)? +1.0 : -1.0)/i;
```

или

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) res += ((i%2)*2 - 1.0)/i;
```

или, если все это кажется высшей математикой :) хотя бы

```
for(int i = 1, sign = -1; i <= n; i++) res += double(sign = -sign)/i;
```

Но стоит дописать рядом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вычислить разность, как получается ряд, сходящийся для x из (-1,1), т.е. для любого аргумента под знаком логарифма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы получить логарифм двойки, надо подставить x = 1/3...

Получаем код типа

```
int n;
double res = 0;
cin >> n;
double x = 1./3, term = x;
for(int i = 1; i <= 2*n; i+=2)
{
    res += term/i;
    term *= x*x;
}
cout << 2*res;
```

Но лучше задавать не количество членов, а точность (последний член ряда должен быть меньше этого значения):

```
double eps = 1e-6, x = 1./3, term = x, res = term;
x*=x;
for(int i = 3; abs(term) > eps; i+=2) res += (term *=x) /i;
res *= 2;

cout << res;
```

Comment: Спасибо. Чем точнее описываешь, тем точнее результат получается - святая истина.

Comment: Ну так давно известно — при неточном ТЗ результат — ХЗ...